# Java - How to check if a GCS storage object exist in a bucket?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, storage

I have a bucket named <Bucket_Name>. I want to check if "User-Info.txt" file exist in <Bucket_Name> or not.

How do I achieve it using Java.

Comment: You should never add Bucket names (or other sensitive data) in your questions, I highly recommend to delete this question and make a new one, in a more focused way; without the bucket name and the things you have tried.

Comment: @MarioGranados: I have now updated the question description and also found the solution. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I sort out the requirement by following the below logic:

```
    public Boolean isObjectExist(String sourceBucketName, String projectId){
            String objectName = "User-Info.txt";
            Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build().getService();
            Bucket bucket = storage.get(sourceBucketName);
                Blob blob = storage.get(sourceBucketName,objectName);
            if (blob != null && blob.exists()){
            return true;
            } else
            return false;
            }
```